# What are some methods of dealing with race conditions between stateless servers on a RDBMS?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, rdbms

We want to avoid zookeeper for now so we don't have too many moving parts.  We may add it later.  For now, I am wondering how I can deal with race conditions on

- insert
- update

For update, we can use optimistic locking(with a version column in the table).  Two inserts just plain fails.  In this way, I suspect I can look for two exception types and retry preventing any race condition.  Under high load, our retries in some records may go to 3 tries to get the record in (I think).

Anyways, I am wondering how others deal with race conditions among a large cluster of server on an RDBMS?  I am looking for potentially better solutions or just plain solutions that get me thinking on different things that can be done around these types of issues.

I remember in noSQL, instead of exceptions it returns the row that was just replaced so you know there was a race so to speak and can deal with that if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect lots of conflicts, use *pessimistic locking*:

```
START TRANSACTION;
-- will lock the row about to be modified
SELECT col FROM tab WHERE id = 42 FOR UPDATE;
/* application activity */
UPDATE tab SET col = 'newval' WHERE id = 42;
COMMIT;
```

If you expect few conflicts, use optimistic locking, either with application tools or by using the `REPEATABLE READ` transaction isolation level.

Comment: what about inserts @Laurenz Albe ?  That only works for existing rows and we frequently have rows created at the same time.

Comment: There is no such conflict with an insert, since an insert is always an atomic operation: either it fails or it works. There is no race condition.

Comment: so the second one fails then and we have to retry, correct?  This is just like our optmistic locking so I am not sure why we would do pessimistic locking then?  Why not just handle updates just like inserts with optimistic locking??

Comment: No, a failing insert never is a race condition. It will fail again if you retry it. That's something different.